# Extract Constraint Name from java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jakarta-ee

Application throws java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException and it has the contraint name as below

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (**CONSTRAINT.UNIQUE_WT**) violated
```

**Question:** Is there a API/direct way to get the constraint name **CONSTRAINT.UNIQUE_WT**  from the exception object (java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)?

Idea is, if I can get the constraint name, I can provide a proper error message.

Comment: According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html) it seems like there is no method provided for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for this, but you can do it using the message provided.

```
String constraint = null;
try {
  ...
} catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
  constraint = e.getMessage.split("**")[1];
}
```